# How do I open blender at less than full screen

Tags: interface

I am a noob at SE and blender, so here we go...
I am using Win10, blender ver. 3.2.1

I would like to open blender at something ***less*** than full screen when I am watching you tube tutorials.

How can I do this?

Comment: open Blender, rescale the window to your like and File>Defaults>Save_Startup_File.

Comment: Thanks Allen and John!
I went with half screen mode of which I was unaware.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is a second monitor, since fitting everything to one will reduce your workspace and also make the video less visible (which is often a problem for identifying nodes, for example).  However, that may be cost prohibitive which is completely understandable.

You could use the side-by-side view layout in Windows.  Select the blender window and press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>.  It will fit to the left half of the screen and your other windows will arrange on the right side where you can select the window you want to fill the right half.

Another way to activate this feature is to grab the title bar of the window and drag it over to the very edge of the screen.  You'll see a border outline expand out to fill half of the screen.  If you release the window it will snap to the highlighted half.

[image: terrible screenshot :(]

Comment: Once you've done what Allen suggests in his last paragraph, you can set that size as default every time Blender starts by going to File > Defaults > Save Startup File in Blender.